# Check agenda of a particular day from calendar

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, calendar

In calendar-mode to invoke d on a specified day, it will prompt the activitiesof the day from file ~/diary.

Is it possible to invoke an agenda view of a particular day from calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just press `c` (which is bound to `org-calendar-goto-agenda`) while the cursor is at the date you wish to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question (@aadcg's answer does that perfectly), but in Emacs you can "look around" and see what keys are bound to what functions in any particular situation (that's part of the "self-documenting" part of the description of Emacs): in this case, while you are in the calendar, say `C-h m`: you'll get all the key bindings available, listed in a separate buffer (which means you can also switch to that buffer and do an interactive search for `org` to find all the keybindings that might have something to do with Org mode).